# AngularFire 2 - FirebaseApp vs FirebaseRef

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to get the ref to enable me to use .update() method. I can exactly use FirebaseApp / FirebaseRef and do this:

```
private ref1: any;
private ref2: any;
constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) fbApp: any, @Inject(FirebaseRef): fbRef: any) {

    this.ref1 = fbApp.database().ref();
    this.ref2 = fbRef.database().ref(); // which work exactly as this.ref1

}
```

What is the difference between FirebaseApp and FirebaseRef? And which one is recommended to use? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both give you a reference to the root of the database. Functionally they do exactly the same. But I find the first one much clearer, so would always use that - unless you're aiming to complicate code maintenance.

Comment: Thanks! When I saw FirebaseRef I was thinking that it works the same as AngularFireDatabase(where you can directly use object/list without .database) like this one this.ref2 = fbRef.ref();

Comment: Yep. `FirebaseRef` is [a deprecated token](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/src/tokens.ts#L9-L11) and will likely be removed. Use `FirebaseApp` as recommended in this answer.